# SSIS ODBC Source not saving password in SQL Server agent job

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc

I'm trying to build a SSIS package which reads a table from ODBC data source (MySQL) and copies the data to an existing table in OLE DB data destination (MS SQL).

It works within Data Tools for SQL, but fails when I try to schedule it using the SQL Server agent job. It seems to forget the password attached in the connection string. When I open the connection manager, the connection string was modified to one without the password substring.

I did find this one: [SSIS package fails ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790105/ssis-package-fails-in-sql-server-agent-but-not-in-visual-studio-odbc-connectio)
But I don't understand how I could use this short answer to solve my problem.

Help is highly appreciated! Struggling with this problem for days now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [protection level](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/) of your package.  The passwords in connection strings are considered "sensitive information" and may not be saved with your package depending on your protection level.

You can change the protection level to ensure that the passwords are saved, but a better way to do this would be to store this information in a configuration file.